# Can't access external SD Card in TWRP after Link2SD

Tags: external-sd, partitions, link2sd, twrp

Ever since I partitioned my SD card for Link2SD, TWRP has been unable to read it. CyanogenMod 12.1 views it fine, but TWRP just shows the card as being 0MB, and freezes when you try to select it.

Is this a format problem, or a problem with TWRP? Am I able to fix this? The card is a 32 GB Class 10 card. The first partition is FAT32 and the second is ext4.

Comment: Is your TWRP latest version? Did you look for whether TWRP supports SD-cards with multiple partitions? If CM 12.1 can easily see and you can use it, this shouldn't be a format problem on TWRP too since it supports both.

Comment: @Firelord TWRP is version 2.7.1.0